# Rails signup no method error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Im not sure if my logic is right but im doing this.. I have administration where i can manually add customer and i have frontend where customer can register.

**customers_controller.rb**

```
class CustomersController < Admin::AdminController
  def new
    @customer = Customer.new
    @customer.build_user
  end

 def create
  @customer = Customer.new(params[:customer])
  ...
 end

 ...
end
```

**fronted_controller.rb**

```
class FrontendController < ApplicationController
  def show_signup
    @customer = Customer.new
    @customer.build_user
    render "signup"
  end

  def signup
    @customer = Customer.new(params[:customer])
    ...
  end
end
```

**routes.rb**

```
  match "signup" => "frontend#show_signup", :via => :get
  match "signup" => "frontend#signup", :via => :post
```

**frontend/signup.html.erb**

```
    <%= form_for @customer, :url => url_for(:controller => 'frontend', :action => 'signup'), :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal' } do |f| %>

<%= f.label :name, :class => 'control-label' %>
<%= f.text_field :name, :class => 'text_field' %>
```

and after showing /signup URL
it throws me an error

```
NoMethodError in Frontend#show_signup undefined method `name' for #<Customer id: nil ...
```

Where is the problem ? I think its okay to access to Customer model from different Controller which is not admin protected..

Models : Customer inherit from User, creating in admin section works good.

**user.rb**

```
belongs_to :customer, :dependent => :destroy
```

...

**customer.rb**

```
has_one :user
...
```

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok i forgot that its nested form so adding

```
<%= f.fields_for :user do |u| %>
```

to **signup.html.erb**
solved error.